# Coluna dinâmica com valor aparecendo errado no WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, grid

Estou com um problema na hora de criar uma tabela com colunas dinâmicas. Eu adiciono as colunas num *loop* for desta forma:

```
for (int i = 0; i < attrIds.Count; i++)
        {
            resource_attr attr = resourceAttrRepository.Find(attrIds[i]);

            int local = i;
            columns.Add(new WebGridColumn()
            {
                ColumnName = attr.code,
                Header = attr.resource_attr_name,
                Style = "column-attr",
                CanSort = true,
                Format = (item) => (((List<string>)item.attrValues).Count < local) ? @item.attrValues[local] : "out"
            });
        }
```

O *header* da coluna fica correto, porém o valor sempre está aparecendo "out".

Estou utilizando ASP.Net MVC 4 e o componente WebGrid.

Answer (score 1):

O Valor sempre aparece OUT porque ele cai no else do if ternário

```
Format = (item) => (((List<string>)item.attrValues).Count < local) ? @item.attrValues[local] : "SEMPRE ESTÁ CAINDO AQUI."
```

Comment: sim, mas pq ele cai sempre no else? debugando vejo que a variável local sempre é maior que a quantidade de objetos dentro da lista item.attrValues